Error uninstalling Zabbix agent
On Windows 10 I uninstalled Zabbix agent 6.4 using Control Panel > Programs and Features > Remove, and the uninstallation completed successfully.
I am installing the agent again on the same machine, and the following message is displayed:

"Please clear the previous agent installation manually (run the previous agent instance with the '--uninstall' option)".
I have checked Programs and Features and the Zabbix agent is not present.
How can I solve this problem in order to have the Zabbix agent installed again?


Run that old version of installer (if this one is newer).
Check if old zabbix_agentd.exe file is still present.


Thank you very much for your answer, which older version of the installer do you want me to install? I have tried installing 6.4.0, 6.4.17 and 6.0 version and I got the same error. Referring to the second point, I have searched the file you mention and i could not find it anywhere. But I have run the services.msc and I have seen that the Zabbix agent service is still there, but it is stopped. How can it be possible? Thanks

Old version - the one you installed earlier, before uninstalling. It was just a guess that installer with exactly same version would behave differently than "wrong" version. I'm not sure.

Service is just a record in a registry. You can clean it up from HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/... Also see a "path to executable" property of this service and check if a file with this path exists.

I ran services.msc and see the Zabbix agent service is there, but it is stopped. How can it be possible?
It's a defect in the installer and/or the product. If any service is in a state where it cannot be stopped in the expected amount of time, this will be the result.
You need to manually delete the service:
sc delete "Zabbix Agent"
You can also enable verbose logging for Windows installer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec
msiexec.exe /i "C:\productname.msi" /L*V "C:\install.log"

Thank you very much, your answer solved my problem and also is helping me a lot. Have a nice day!
